# Compress data on a key word in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a test table like this-

```
Field
A
B
C
END
D
E 
F 
END
G
H
I
END
```

I want to compress this data on key word "END" in this format-

```
Field
A|B|C
D|E|F
G|H|I
```

Tried using Monarch Pro but could not get the desired results. I really can't think of a way to start on this in SQL. Please help.

Comment: Is "Field" the only column in your table?

Comment: Yes. And the problem is the no of rows between two consecutive "End" may vary. Only leverage I have is this key word.

Comment: I don't know any possible way, then, since you can't reliably order by Field, and know which rows the key word occurs between.   Maybe you can handle this in your front end app?

Comment: Yes cant use order by on Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help.

```
DECLARE @WORD VARCHAR(300)
SELECT @WORD = COALESCE(@WORD + '|','') + Field  FROM [YourTable]
SELECT @WORD = REPLACE(@WORD, 'END', '$')

SELECT @WORD Field INTO #A

;WITH c(FieldOutput, Field) as (
select CAST(LEFT(Field, CHARINDEX('$',Field+'$')-2) AS VARCHAR(100)),
    STUFF(Field, 1, CHARINDEX('$',Field+'$')+1, '')
from #A
where ISNULL(Field, '') <> ''
union all
select CAST(LEFT(Field, CHARINDEX('$',Field+'$')-2) AS VARCHAR(100)),
    STUFF(Field, 1, CHARINDEX('$',Field+'$')+1, '')
from c
where ISNULL(Field, '') <> ''
)

select FieldOutput AS Field
from c
```

**EDIT**

Created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8e88/1) to test this out.

Comment: I actually have over 1 million rows. The code has been running for over 10 hrs now. Will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Can you try this out on a smaller table first to see if it works for you? Try a `SELECT TOP 1000 * INTO...` construct to populate some temp table and check it.

Comment: Already done that. It works fine. But waiting for the results on the complete data set taking Varchar(max).

Comment: I think since my solution works you should be marking this as an answer. If it works for 10 odd records, it is going to work for a million records too. But you, instead of trying to figure out *how* to do this, should try to check *why* to do this. A complex calculation on a million records is obviously a sticky situation and must be ridden of, if possible. Having data in this manner is something you should be trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

High level approach:

Use a cursor to step through the table row by row.

Append to a temporary variable until the row reads 'END' then write the contents of the temp variable to a row on a different table.

Iterate through until you reach the end of the table.

There is probably a more elegant, non-cursor based way of doing this, but this will get the job done.

Comment: Without being able to use ORDER BY, there's no guarantee you will step through the table in the order that you intend.